# How to check if image has been flipped?

Tags: python

I have two characters that move according to WASD, and the arrow keys. I want the characters to flip in the x-axis in accordance to if they're moving left or right. But if I just make them flip as soon as the left or right has been pressed then the characters flip even if they are facing the right direction.

I would try and compare the characters images to the one I have saved on my computer but I had to flip player 2 to make them face the each other.

In short, how do I check if the character is already facing the right direction (has been flipped) before flipping them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add 2 variables that store the current direction of the image (for each character) and then check it and set it every time you flip a character.

It doesn't have to be 2 vars, you can store the information in any format you would like (`list, dictionary, string`)

Comment: Ive got the 2 variables to match against, with the if statement working, but any method I used to flip the image isn't working. How do I work around this.

Comment: I wouldn't know, you didn't share any code